# how to validate a form using a javascript file and redirecting the file to another php page through a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have used script tag under the head tag with the attribute src="formvalidation.js".

In form tag I have used the attributes `action="login.php"` and `onSubmit="return formvalidation();"`.

Without performing any validation.the form gets submitted and redirected to login.php.

Comment: does `formvalidation()` return always true ? does it `preventDefault()` ?

Comment: Could you post the content of your `formvalidation.js` file, as well as the complete HTML of you form? That would help.

Comment: The name of the script file (`formvalidation.js`) is not the same thing as the function call. The `onSubmit` calls a function, not a file. Functions live inside files. You need to look at what is inside the `formvalidation.js` file.